# Min and Max values in n-dimension stack Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, stack, min

Hi have the following `raster arrays` stacked as `numpy.stack` with values between -30 and -2:

```
print(data.shape)
(3, 6382, 7122)
```

I want to produce a new `numpy.array` called `minVal` where I extract the minimun value for all the array cells (pixels) using all the layers of the stack

So if cell `[24,78]` in `data[0], data[1], data[2]` is `-8, -30 , -15` respectivley, the retrived value should be `-30`

How should I proceed? I guess the same procedure should apply for the maximum value. In the end, I would like to stack minVal and maxVal together

So far I have tried with:

```
minVal = data.min(axis=0)
maxVal = data.max(axis=0)
Diff = maxVal - minVal

test = np.dstack(Diff, minVal, maxVal)
```

But I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: In relation with a deleted comment: Same error. Actually, I am not very sure of what `axis=` is doing. I guess it is there where you choose in which array dimension you want to compute the `min`?

Answer (score 0):

If think what you are looking for is simply:

```
test = np.array([Diff, minVal, maxVal])

test.shape
(3, 6382, 7122)
```